# Concat list of dataframes containing empty dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this list of dataframes and some of them are Empty. I do not want to discard them as it would change my number of rows when I concatenate it. I want to convert them into NA values so that these 5 dataframes are converted to 5 rows.

List of dataframes:

```
[                 0              1              2      3
 0  102,000,000.00    2,000,000.00  1,400,000.00   0.00 , Empty DataFrame
 Columns: []
 Index: [], Empty DataFrame
 Columns: []
 Index: [], Empty DataFrame
 Columns: []
 Index: [],                 0              1      2      3
 0  60,900,000.00    1,300,000.00  0.00   0.00 ]
```

Code:

```
data = pd.concat(dataframes)
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Output:

```
0   102,000,000.00  2,000,000.00    1,400,000.00    0.00
0   60,900,000.00   1,300,000.00    0.00            0.00
```

Desired Output:

```
0   102,000,000.00  2,000,000.00    1,400,000.00    0.00
0   NA                   NA           NA             NA
0   NA                   NA           NA             NA
0   NA                   NA           NA             NA
0   60,900,000.00   1,300,000.00    0.00            0.00
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend a list comprehension approach where you update the empty data frames with a template data frame:

```
template = pd.DataFrame(data = [[pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA]], columns = [0,1,2,3])
dataframes= [i if not i.empty else template for i in dataframes]
```

This updates data frames where `i.empty == True` with the data frame defined in `template`.  A working example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = [[102000000,2000000,1400000,0]], columns = [0,1,2,3])
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df3 = pd.DataFrame()
df4 = pd.DataFrame()
df5 = pd.DataFrame(data = [[102000000,2000000,1400000,0]], columns = [0,1,2,3])

dataframes = [df1, df2, df3,df4,df5]

template = pd.DataFrame(data = [[pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA]], columns = [0,1,2,3])

dataframes= [i if not i.empty else template for i in dataframes]

pd.concat(dataframes)

           0        1        2     3
0  102000000  2000000  1400000     0
0       <NA>     <NA>     <NA>  <NA>
0       <NA>     <NA>     <NA>  <NA>
0       <NA>     <NA>     <NA>  <NA>
0  102000000  2000000  1400000     0
```