# Remove warning when using concat() with empty dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My old code concats some dataframes, some may be empty. I now receive two future warnings regarding this.

My goal is to have the old logic but without any warnings. Mainly I need to **retain all the column names without empty rows**.

I wrote the code below (fixed 1 of the 2 warning) but it still gives me `FutureWarning: The behavior of DataFrame concatenation with empty or all-NA entries is deprecated.`

```
import io
import pandas as pd

df_list = ['RevisionTime,Data,2019/Q2,2019/Q3,2019/Q4\r\n',
           'RevisionTime,Data,2019/Q3\r\n2019-08-17,10.5,10.5\r\n',
           'RevisionTime,Data,2019/Q3\r\n2019-09-18 08:10:00,51.0,51.0\r\n',
           'RevisionTime,Data,2019/Q3\r\n2019-10-18 08:10:00,111.5,111.5\r\n',
           'RevisionTime,Data,2019/Q3,2019/Q4\r\n2019-11-15 22:31:00,182.0,111.5,70.5\r\n']

# list with dataframes
df_list = [pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(df)) for df in df_list]

# to avoid 'The behaviour of array concatenation with empty entries is deprecated.'
# and to retain all column names
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63970182/concat-list-of-dataframes-containing-empty-dataframes
for i, df in enumerate(df_list):
    col_length = len(df.columns)
    template = pd.DataFrame(data=[[pd.NA] * col_length], columns=df.columns)
    df_list[i] = df if not df.empty else template
#

res_df = pd.concat(df_list) # warning here
res_df = res_df.dropna(how='all') # remove empty rows
print(res_df)
```

Output dataframe should look like:

```
          RevisionTime   Data 2019/Q2  2019/Q3  2019/Q4
0           2019-08-17   10.5     NaN     10.5      NaN
0  2019-09-18 08:10:00   51.0     NaN     51.0      NaN
0  2019-10-18 08:10:00  111.5     NaN    111.5      NaN
0  2019-11-15 22:31:00  182.0     NaN    111.5     70.5
```

Basically, help me fix the code to remove the warning.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77254777/alternative-to-concat-of-empty-dataframe-now-that-it-is-being-deprecated

Comment: maybe use `if/else` to skip code when you have empty `dataframe`

Comment: or maybe you should use `print()` to check if you don't create empty `template`.

Comment: I need empty frames to have the columns from them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Index with all possible column names and then reindex the final dataframe:

```py
# create `column_names` index with all posible column names
column_names = pd.Index([])
for df in df_list:
    column_names = column_names.union(df.columns)

res_df = pd.concat([df for df in df_list if not df.empty])

# reindex the final dataframe (this adds NaN to missing columns)
res_df = res_df.reindex(column_names, axis=1)
print(res_df)
```

Prints:

```
   2019/Q2  2019/Q3  2019/Q4   Data         RevisionTime
0      NaN     10.5      NaN   10.5           2019-08-17
0      NaN     51.0      NaN   51.0  2019-09-18 08:10:00
0      NaN    111.5      NaN  111.5  2019-10-18 08:10:00
0      NaN    111.5     70.5  182.0  2019-11-15 22:31:00
```